# How do I set the intent extra dynamically based on the type of variable received in the Json?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Json in a server response which has the entire intent data. I also get extras to be added to the intent. 
Now, the extras can vary in data type. int, long, boolean etc. 
How do I pass these extra values to the intent which I create in the necessary type? 
The putExtra method has string as a key and a few overloads based upon the type of value. 
How do I decide which one to use?

Comment: You would need to add some of the code you are working with and where you are stuck to get help. Until then, I would suggest using an `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on contracts of json parser, Intent receiver.

If protocol is undefined - heuristically (switch, if/else).

Also you can try gson, it doesn't solve problem with types, but transit can be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Parse the json using gson library http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

create the model class and implements serializable.

Example:-
    public class TemplateCommonMetaData implements Serializable {

```
@SerializedName("code")
public boolean sCode;

@SerializedName("message")
public String message; }
```

and set serializable objet in intent
   in.putExtra("key", serializableobject);